# Upload Video to server from android sdcard

Tags: android, multithreading, xampp

This is my code.

```
package com.example.upload;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    Button b;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("Uploading file path :- '/storage/sdcard/android_1.png'");

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        tv.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    }
                                });                      
                         int response= uploadFile("/storage/sdcard/android_1.png");
                         System.out.println("RES : " + response);                         
                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
        });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
          String upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2/upload_test/upload_media_test.php";
          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 
          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
           return 0;
          }
              try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {
                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);               
                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
               if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {  
              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {
              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();
//              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismis`enter code here`s();       
          return serverResponseCode;  
         } 
}
```

it gives following error.

```
Http response is : not found: 404
RES : 404
skipped 119 frames! The application may be doing too many work on its main thread
skipped 63 frames! The application may be doing too many work on its main thread
skipped 79 frames! The application may be doing too many work on its main thread
```

Can anyone please tell,What is the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code....

Its working for me.

String fileName = sourceFileUri; // Use Your video file Path or Uri

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null; 
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" );

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"                             +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);




            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); 
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename="
                    + fileName + "" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        File se = new File(full_path_name);

                        String ser = se.getName();

                        String string =full_path_name;
                        String[] parts = string.split("/");
                        String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
                        String part2 = parts[1]; 
                        String part3 = parts[2];
                        String part4 = parts[3];
                        String msg = "http://172.17.2.139/manimca/smartcomplaints/Images/"+part4;


                        //    messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
                           try
                        {
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.17.2.139/yourpath/yourfoldername/yourphppage.php");
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            is = entity.getContent();
                            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
                        }

                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }     

                        try
                        {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            is.close();
                            result = sb.toString();
                            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
                        }     

                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

                            if(code==1)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });               
            }   
            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            finish();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss(); 
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss(); 
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "No Internet Connection ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e); 
        }
        dialog.dismiss();      
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
```

Comment: thank you @mani mca Android Developer
here you have mentioned 
"String msg = "http://172.17.2.139/manimca/smartcomplaints/Images/"+part4;"
line.here what is 172.17.2.139?